# Changing upload size

Tags: 7

I tried all solutions from google and i can not figure out how to increase from 2 MB to 70MB.

In WHM i did changes like from screenshots:
[image]
[image]

On the Drupal site, it went up to 8MB; whatever I tried with .htaccess, settings.php, it won't go more then 8. Adding php.ini to the Drupal root folder throws a fatal error.

I tried changing file upload size on image field to 65 and 75 MB, it gets saved but on node add, it still says 8 MB

How can I change the upload size globally ? I have access to WHM, Cpanel, SSH, FTP, root, whatever. Server is private, dedicated. Many mentioned changing php.ini, but where is it ? On various answers its on various places and i want to change this globally.

Comment: What does "WHM" mean?

Comment: It's the UI that sits on top of cPanel these days @cilefen

Comment: @cilefen It's the [Web Host Manager](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/webhost-manager-whm/what-is-whm-web-host-manager).

Comment: **You need to [restart your server (Apache)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dHgjC.jpg) in order for changes to take effect.**

Comment: Yep, i did that after changing the values.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) value in php.ini

Comment: Where is it located and do i need to edit it through SSH or ftp ?

Comment: @AzzKawa SSH located in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your problem has to do with your php.ini: at worst, Your server should ignore it (it would be useful to know a little bit more about your server environment: shared? Godaddy?).

Here's what your php.ini should have (exclusively):

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 70M
```

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 70M

It would be useful if you posted your php.ini file, to understand your problem better.

Comment: Since the OP is using WHM, I assume they cannot access the php.ini file directly. The WHM is a UI that allows to change the PHP settings, among other things.

Comment: Yes, but if Drupal crashes, it signals to me that the local php.ini is being read (otherwise, the hosting service only ignores it). HostGator does mention (http://support.hostgator.com/articles/what-is-php-ini) that you can use the php.ini, using a specific location (it even provides examples).

Comment: I have total control of the WHM, Cpanel, SSH, root. Private dedicated server.

Comment: I just tried with setting up one image file to 65 and 75MB, it does get saved, but when creating the content it still says 8 MB max.

Comment: So you were able to upload the file into Drupal? If the label is wrong, try clearing the cache.

Comment: There's an additional test you can do just to discard php.info completely:

* Create an empty file called info.php in your Drupal root
* Edit the file and enter a single line of code: <?php phpinfo() ?> and save it
* Open it in your browser as http://yoursite/info.php

This gives you the statistics of the php configuration for your Drupal root. Do a find with your browser for "post_max_size" and "upload_max_filesize", and see if they match your expectations.

Comment: It also lets you know where the actual php.ini file you are using is, as signaled by "Loaded Configuration File" (use your browser find functionality).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the max size on the file field configuration needs increasing. You must increase both. Also check the effective size limit at /admin/reports/status/php. You may not be able to exceed a pre-set maximum without contacting the hosting provider.

Comment: I have not tried to increase in the file size in field itself as i have control over WHM, and changing the first value as i wrote in question did bring results, increased file size, but to max of 8mb. Since i have ton of image, video, file fields i just want to figure out where exaclly is this stored and how can i change it globally. WHM: CloudLinux, CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core).

Comment: Updated question with all details.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Drupal has settings for the maximum size allowed for uploaded files in different places.

For example, in admin/config/people/accounts you set the maximum size the file for the image associated with user accounts can have, both as dimensions in pixels and as file size.

> [image: screenshot]

For content types with a field to upload and attach an image to its nodes, there is a setting for that field. (See admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/field_image for the *Article* content type and its default *Image* field.)

> [image: screenshot]

In the case the file size is not set, users will be allowed to upload a file basing on the upload limits set in PHP. (In my case, that is 2 MB, as reported from the field description.)

The same is true when a content type has a field to upload a file.

> [image: screenshot]

The same is true for other entities to which is possible to add a file for uploading a file or an image. Each field, for each entity, and each bundle of that entity, has a setting for the maximum size of the uploaded files.

So, it can be the PHP settings has been effectively changed, but Drupal is still using its limits set in different places. To be sure, go to admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/field_image (if you didn't remove the content type or altered the *Image* field): Drupal will tell you the limit set by PHP.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Like @kmbremner and @Antonio Hernandez answered post_max_size should be increased also. Here is a screenshot for newbies in WHM like myself.

In PHP configuration editor, switch to advanced mode and close to the bottom you will find post_max_size which was 8M by default. Do not forget that you need to change max_upload_filesize also.

In Drupal if you leave max file size blank for an upload field (image, video, file), it will read global php values.

[image]